# Create a function that count the number of users which represent a certain sexe and a certain category in R

Tags: r, function

I have a dataframe called "hcv" with each rows associated to one user, showing his sexe and his blood category (0, 0s , 1 ,2 or 3). Sexe and Category variables are both factor in my dataset.

I need to create a function that ask me a sexe and a category and return me the number of user which answer to both arguments.

so far this is what I have :

```
pow <- function(sexe, category) {

  result <- sum(numbers == sexe, by = Category)
  print(paste(result))
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

should be enough:

```
sum( Sexe == sexe & category == Category )
```

also perhaps look at:

```
hcv %>% table( Sexe, Category )
```